# mysql display data from two table using foreign key

Tags: mysql, database

I have two table.
One table, *vessellist*, has **vesselno** as the primary key. The other table is *restowlist*, and the primary key is **containerno** and the foreign key is **vesselno**.

I want to display data where when the user select the vesselno, it will display all the containerno that has the same vesselno in the restowlist.

*vesselno*: **emmamearsk**

**containerno**

---

1) 900408

2) 880202

3) 900020

I've tried the join table, but its a messed up.

Comment: What query did you try ? INNER JOIN is the right way to achieve that ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with inner join

```
 SELECT containerno
 FROM vessellist v
 INNER JOIN   restowlist r  ON  v.vesselno = r.vesselno
 WHERE v.vesselno = 'emmamearsk';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT containerno
FROM vessellist v, restowlist r
WHERE v.vesselno = r.vesselno
AND v.vesselno = 'emmamearsk';
```